# jquery calling function from button created by plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I have a very simple jquery plugin that creates a button and appends it to the element:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.somePlugin = function(element, options) {

    var button = '<button>Hello World</button>';
    $(element).append(button);

    var sayHello = function(){
      alert('Hello World');
    }

  };
})(jQuery);
```

My question is, how do I call the sayHello function when the button is clicked? TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your HTML code into a jQuery object using `$('<button>Hello World</button>')`, and then you can attack a `click` event to it like you would with any other jQuery object:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.somePlugin = function(element, options) {

    var button = '<button>Hello World</button>';

    var sayHello = function(){
      alert('Hello World');
    }
    var $button = $(button).click(sayHello);
    $(element).append($button);

  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a jQuery object, bind the click event with the object then append it to the container element.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.somePlugin = function(element, options) {
    var sayHello = function() {
      alert('Hello World');
    }

    var button = $('<button>Hello World</button>');
    button.on('click', sayHello);  
    button.appendTo(element);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

plugin code:

```
(function ($) {

    $.fn.somePlugin = function (el, options) {

        var $el = $(this);

        $el.append("<button>Hello World</button>");

        $el.on("click", "button", function(){
          alert("Hello World");
        });
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Simple html:

```
<div id="target"></div>
```

Usage of plugin:

```
$("#target").somePlugin();
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/628fua1g/) test